# What is the best DBMS to run Ruby on Rails apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I have seen many people use MySQL, some Postgres and I know I have seen an Oracle adapter somewhere. But really - what should I use just starting out with my first Rails apps?

Comment: Anything that works. Unless you have very specific requirements, anything will do.

Comment: I second that. If you don't have any requirements, why not just use sqlite3, especially on Linux? Easy to install, no configuration, is created by default in Rails, so no need to change the configuration.

Answer (score 3):

If you ask such question then probably there is no real difference for you.

Usually a specific DBMS is selected depending on:

- Infrastructure limitations (e.g. Heroku provides only Postgres by
  default).
- Personal preferences (a space of endless holywars).

If you don't have neither first nor second, then choose the most popular, because the most popular means the most supported.

Answer (score 1):

Your first app you should just use sqlite because it's easy and there's no setup required. You'll have enough to worry about with the rails framework, ruby, tdd, etc. Once you get better you should look into postgres. It's what is used by Heroku and most of the rubyists I admire mention their preference for postgres over MySql. I'm sorry but I don't have any specific links for this bias but I've seen it mentioned many times.